# Optimize Bigquery query: Shuffle reached broadcast limit

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I'm trying to process this query.

```
SELECT
r.src,r.dst, ROUND(r.price/50)*50 pb,COUNT(*) results
FROM [search.interesting_routes] ovr
LEFT JOIN [search.search_results2] r ON ovr.src=r.src AND     ovr.dst=r.dst
WHERE DATE(r.saved_at) >= '2015-10-1' AND DATE(r.saved_at) <= '2015-10-01'  AND r.price < 20000
GROUP BY pb, r.src, r.dst
ORDER BY pb
```

The table *search_results2* contains a huge amout of search results about prices for routes (route is defined by *src* and *dst*).
I need to count all records in *search_results2* for each record in *interesting_routes* for different price buckets.

The query works fine on small sample of data, but once the data is huge it ends with

> Error: Shuffle reached broadcast limit for table __I0 (broadcasted at
>   least 176120970 bytes). Consider using partitioned joins instead of
>   broadcast joins.

I have a difficulty to rewrite the SELECT with usage of suggested partitioned join. Or at least get the result somehow.

Comment: Can you try JOIN EACH, instead of JOIN?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa not sure what this error means, but I got it to for some older query even posted a bug report about and no one have verified it.

Comment: this was on 1st october: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=334&sort=-id

Comment: Sorry for the slow response on the issue tracker. Per my update there, this should produce the error message:

Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins

Comment: A have tried JOIN EACH  instead of JOIN with result: "Resources exceeded during query execution."